# Entity Framework Linq Query on a Many to Many Relationship?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public bool HasPermission(string permission)
    {
        return Roles.Any(r => r.Role.Permissions
                  .Any(p => p.Name == permission));
    }
    // Some other Stuff

}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : this()
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
 }

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    public ApplicationUserRole(): base() { }

    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Basically they map to five tables: Users, Roles, UserRoles, Permissions and RolePermissions - currently I don't have a model for RolePermission - Do I need one?

I want to get a list of permissions for a given user using linq with lambda expressions, something similar to the following SQL:

```
Select p.Id, p.Name 
From Permission p
inner join RolePermission rp on rp.PermissionId = p.Id
inner join UserRole ur on ur.RoleId = rp.RoleId 
where ur.UserId = 'xyz'
```

I'm not sure which entity I start with to get a list of permissions using LINQ - I can only manage to get to the roles using the following?

```
var permissions =  _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId)
                               .SelectMany(r => r.Roles.SelectMany(p => p.Role.Permissions))
                               .ToList();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe LinqKit can help you.

http://codigosimples.net/2014/05/09/criando-query-dinamicas-entity-framework-com-linqkit/

Comment: `SelectMany(r => r.Roles)`

Comment: @Gert how does `SelectMany(r => r.Roles)` give me a list of permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out as follows:

```
var permissions =  _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId)
                           .SelectMany(r => r.Roles.SelectMany(p => p.Role.Permissions)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To do a join in Linq you could use something like this.

```
var permissions = new List<Permission>(){ 
                  new Permission (){
                                      Id= 1, 
                                      Name = "Test1"
                                   }, 
                  new Permission{     Id = 2, 
                                      Name = "Test2"}
};
var applicationRoles = new List<ApplicationRole>(){
                       new ApplicationRole{ 
                                            Id =1, 
                                            PermissionId = 2
    }};

var x = from p in permissions
        join ar in applicationRoles on p.Id equals ar.PermissionId
        select p;


public class Permission{
public byte Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}

public List<ApplicationRole> Roles {get;set;}
}


public class ApplicationRole {
public byte Id {get;set;}   
public byte PermissionId {get;set;}
}
```

I'm not sure if that's what you actually asking, so i hope it helps you.

Comment: need a where clause to get permissions for a given user?